# Is there a noun that represents a set of interactions?

Tags: single-word-requests

When discussing human interactions such as a conversation, an email, an online chat, or a postcard, is there a noun that can be used to describe the entire set of interactions?

Obviously the plural form 'interactions' fits most scenarios but a separate word to describe this would be preferable.

Since this is specifically communication interactions a word from a participants perspective could be used instead of a generic term.

**Update**

Ideally the word in question would not itself be replaceable with the word 'interaction' or vice versa. We've tied ourselves in knots of misunderstanding when talking about this since we've been unable to come up with a term that means 'group of interactions' which isn't itself an interaction. 'Communication' isn't a perfect candidate since it too can be used to describe the set as well as an instance.

Comment: Doesn't _communications_ (with both a plural count and a mass usage) work?

Comment: Correspondence or correspondences?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I actually thought exactly that as was writing the question! It indeed could but I thought I'd carry on to see what other suggestions might be proffered.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a word that fits your requirements. It's pretty common to use the same word to mean a general concept and specific instances. Why exclude such words? It's usually clear from context which is meant.

Comment: Does *discourse* fit the idea of what you're looking for?

Comment: @Bramar I agree if it was clear from context there wouldn't be an issue. Think of my scenario as a modelling exercise; it's very important in discussions that all are clear when we are talking about a single interaction vs a theoretical entity that represents multiple interactions. A name for the theoretical entity is what I'm after (or a different name for an interaction instance which could not also represent the entity).

Answer (score 1):

My preferred suggestion is **dialogue**, or if you want to emphasize the plurality of the interactions, then you might prefer **dialogues**.

> 2.b: an exchange of ideas and opinions <organized a series of *dialogues* on human rights>

--[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dialogue)

Despite the contrast with monologue, a speech by one person, the "di-" in dialogue does not mean two. Rather ["dia-" is from Greek meaning "across,"](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=dialogue&allowed_in_frame=0) so a dialogue is a conversation between two *or more* people.

> Mistaken belief that it can only mean "conversation between two persons" is from confusion of dia- and di- (1); the error goes back to at least 1532, when trialogue was coined needlessly for "a conversation between three persons."

--[Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=dialogue&allowed_in_frame=0)

### Fancy words

If dialogue or dialogues is too boring for you, then **colloquy** (plural, colloquies) or **colloquium** (plural, colloquiums or colloquia) might suit your taste.

> colloquy (n.)
>
> mid-15c., "discourse," from Latin *colloquium* "conference, conversation," literally "a speaking together," from *com*- "together" + -*loquium* "speaking," from *loqui* "to speak".

--[Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=colloquy&allowed_in_frame=0)

Contrast with soliloquy:

> 1: the act of talking to oneself

--[Merriam-Websters](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/soliloquy)

Colloquium has a [strong connotation of a meeting](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/colloquium) of multiple people in specific place within a specific time, however, so it is not as generic as colloquy or dialogue.

### Conclusion

**Dialogue** must involve more than one communicator and is an easily accessible word. **Dialogues** emphasizes a set of interactions but is more bulky. **Colloquy** signals to the reader that the interactions are somehow more sophisticated than a simple, one-time interaction but the word is slightly ostentatious. **Colloquies** reinforces the plurality of the interactions but could be distracting to your readers. Finally, **colloquium**, colloquiums, or colloquia might be best in some rare situations.

Answer (score 0):

(AmE)

A single pair of e-mail messages (query/response) or even a few (e.g. query/response/request for clarification/clarification/acknowledgement) might be termed an "exchange".

A continuous set of e-mail interactions (questions, responses, comments etc), on the same topic (Subject line), whether between two correspondents or many, is called a "thread".

Note that like a physical thread, an e-mail thread can get broken (if one correspondent decided to contine the exchange, not by replying, but by addressing a new message to the same person, which drops the context of the previous exchanges).

Also, a thread can "branch" when one one member of a multiple-person tthread redirects his response ("forwards") to additional person(s), without including all existing parties.

Worse  yet, a member of a multiple-person thread might inadvertently fail to "Reply All" and instead reply only to the latest messager, thus turning a multi-person thread into a two-person thread. The recipient of such a reply might quickly try to patch the break, by cc-ing all the other parties, but this creates a "branch" if other parties reply to the original "all-parties" thread and others to the broken-and-patched thread.  At this point the thread is "branched", and runs the risk of devolving into something less than communication. (I don't know whether there is a term for a thread that becomes irretrievably non-useful due to such branching).

The term "thread" can also apply to interactions on sites such as this one (here, each question has a "thread" of comments for the question itself, and a separate comment "thread" for each answer.)  On this site, threads don't actually branch, as all posts appear to all readers, but they run the risk of getting intertwined  (dare I say "braided") as various posters reply to various other commenters, across days and time zones).

With text messages, the set of interactions between two parties is sometimes called a "conversation." as in "Delete entire conversation?". However, this does not necessarily correspond to the usual sense of "conversation", because one can easily continue the saved thread (sic) on another day, taking up a completely new topic. My mobile counts it as part of the same "conversation" anytime I address a person with whom I have communicated previously, if I fail to delete that older "conversation" first.

Sending postcards via snail-mail is too disjointed in time to be called literally a "conversation". It would rightly be referred to by the old-fashioned term "correspondence".

Comment: That's an excellent set of options. Nothing jumps out as being perfect but I have a feeling nothing perfectly fits my request. We could easily take one of your terms and through usage make it mean what we need, especially since terms such as 'thread' definitively refer to more than one. I won't accept the answer just yet but it's likely.

Answer (score 0):

Would "interlocution" be something that works in the stated situation?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: @Mari-LouA This isn't the best answer but it *is* an answer. I'm brand new here as well but this seems harsh and inaccurate; your comment is less relevant to their answer than their answer was to my question.

Comment: @JRoughan  Apart from the fact user293129 has answered your question with another, the post consists of one word: "interlocution". If you have found this answer to be helpful, then by all means upvote it. If you haven't (and this is true for me) then encouraging the user to explain why is your best option.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Agreed, but it really looks like you've misplaced a cookie-cut response. They do want to ask other users "What is the meaning of interlocution" like you suggest, they simply phrased their reply in the form of a question. Not a question of meaning but of suitability to my, possibly unclear, requirements. Why discourage helpful new users? A simple suggestion to avoid this kind of phrasing would surely be better.

Comment: Sorry if my answer was terse. It was merely a suggestion to explore the possibility since "interlocutor" is a word defined as someone you have an exchange with, but "interlocution" is not found in your average dictionary (don't know about OED though), hence from interlocutor OP might be able to create interlocution if that satisfies his needs. I saw it as a response in the shape of a rhetorical question. If those aren't considered proper, I will stop using them.